# org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException

Tags: stream, jedis, spring-data-redis

I have an application which reads data from redis. I am getting the below exception stack

```
 org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Cannot deserialize; nested exception is org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to deserialize payload. Is the byte array a result of corresponding serialization for DefaultDeserializer?; nested exception is java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 7B226C65
        at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.deserialize(JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.java:41) ~[spring-data-redis-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.deserializeHashValue(AbstractOperations.java:296) ~[spring-data-redis-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.deserializeHashMap(AbstractOperations.java:257) ~[spring-data-redis-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultHashOperations.entries(DefaultHashOperations.java:227) ~[spring-data-redis-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
        at com.engine.Template.getDataFromMap(Template.java:38) ~[classes/:?]
        at com.engine.Utils.getLevelInfoFrom(Utils.java:199) ~[classes/:?]
        at com.engine.Utils.getData(Utils.java:368) ~[classes/:?]
        at com.engine.controller.TicketController.process(TicketController.java:56) ~[classes/:?]
        at com.engine.jms.JmsMessageReceiver.onMessage(JmsMessageReceiver.java:56) [classes/:?]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:746) [spring-jms-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:684) [spring-jms-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:651) [spring-jms-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:315) [spring-jms-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:253) [spring-jms-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1150) [spring-jms-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1142) [spring-jms-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1039) [spring-jms-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_74]
Caused by: org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to deserialize payload. Is the byte array a result of corresponding serialization for DefaultDeserializer?; nested exception is java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 7B226C65
        at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.DeserializingConverter.convert(DeserializingConverter.java:78) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.DeserializingConverter.convert(DeserializingConverter.java:36) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.deserialize(JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.java:39) ~[spring-data-redis-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
        ... 17 more
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 7B226C65
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:806) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:299) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
        at org.springframework.core.ConfigurableObjectInputStream.<init>(ConfigurableObjectInputStream.java:64) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.ConfigurableObjectInputStream.<init>(ConfigurableObjectInputStream.java:50) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.serializer.DefaultDeserializer.deserialize(DefaultDeserializer.java:68) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.DeserializingConverter.convert(DeserializingConverter.java:73) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.DeserializingConverter.convert(DeserializingConverter.java:36) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.deserialize(JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.java:39) ~[spring-data-redis-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
        ... 17 more
```

I have tried searching the solution on other forums as well, but I dont see any solutions. Below is my block of code

```java
    String receivedJSON = (String) redisTemplate.opsForHash().get(redisKey, hashKey);
```

If someone has found any solutions or even faced this issue, please respond.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got a solution for this. The problem was that the hashValue should be serialized using string serializer. After setting the Default serializer as string serializer, I was able to find the solution and finish my requirement.

```xml
    <bean id="redisTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate"
            p:connection-factory-ref="redisConnectionFactory">
            <property name="defaultSerializer" ref="stringSerializer" />
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="stringSerializer"
            class="org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.StringRedisSerializer" />
```

Comment: This saved me. redisTemplate.setDefaultSerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());